Detecting all uint_fastN_t and uint_leastN_t in _Generic
For code:
#include <stdint.h>

#define IS_UNSIGNED1(T)                 \
    _Generic((T),                       \
        uint_fast8_t : 1,               \
        uint_fast16_t: 1,               \
        uint_fast32_t: 1,               \
        uint_fast64_t: 1,               \
        default      : 0                \
    )

#define IS_UNSIGNED(T)                   \
    _Generic((T),                        \
        uint_least8_t : 1,               \
        uint_least16_t: 1,               \
        uint_least32_t: 1,               \
        uint_least64_t: 1,               \
        default       : IS_UNSIGNED1(T)  \
    )

int main(void)
{
    IS_UNSIGNED((uint_least8_t){0});
}

I am getting the following errors:
<source>: In function 'main':
<source>:7:9: error: '_Generic' specifies two compatible types
    7 |         uint_fast32_t: 1,               \
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:18:25: note: in expansion of macro 'IS_UNSIGNED1'
   18 |         default       : IS_UNSIGNED1(T)  \
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:23:5: note: in expansion of macro 'IS_UNSIGNED'
   23 |     IS_UNSIGNED((uint_least8_t){0});
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:6:9: note: compatible type is here
    6 |         uint_fast16_t: 1,               \
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:18:25: note: in expansion of macro 'IS_UNSIGNED1'
   18 |         default       : IS_UNSIGNED1(T)  \
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:23:5: note: in expansion of macro 'IS_UNSIGNED'
   23 |     IS_UNSIGNED((uint_least8_t){0});
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:8:9: error: '_Generic' specifies two compatible types
    8 |         uint_fast64_t: 1,               \
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:18:25: note: in expansion of macro 'IS_UNSIGNED1'
   18 |         default       : IS_UNSIGNED1(T)  \
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:23:5: note: in expansion of macro 'IS_UNSIGNED'
   23 |     IS_UNSIGNED((uint_least8_t){0});
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:6:9: note: compatible type is here
    6 |         uint_fast16_t: 1,               \
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:18:25: note: in expansion of macro 'IS_UNSIGNED1'
   18 |         default       : IS_UNSIGNED1(T)  \
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:23:5: note: in expansion of macro 'IS_UNSIGNED'
   23 |     IS_UNSIGNED((uint_least8_t){0});
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:8:9: error: '_Generic' specifies two compatible types
    8 |         uint_fast64_t: 1,               \
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:18:25: note: in expansion of macro 'IS_UNSIGNED1'
   18 |         default       : IS_UNSIGNED1(T)  \
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:23:5: note: in expansion of macro 'IS_UNSIGNED'
   23 |     IS_UNSIGNED((uint_least8_t){0});
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:7:9: note: compatible type is here
    7 |         uint_fast32_t: 1,               \
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:18:25: note: in expansion of macro 'IS_UNSIGNED1'
   18 |         default       : IS_UNSIGNED1(T)  \
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:23:5: note: in expansion of macro 'IS_UNSIGNED'
   23 |     IS_UNSIGNED((uint_least8_t){0});
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
Compiler returned: 1

which tells me that the uint_leastN_t types and the uint_fastN_t can be compatible among themselves (I found nothing in the Standard that stated that they can not). Do I now have to resort to 8 levels of indirection to detect all 8 types, or is there a better way?
(I currently have 10 levels of indirection to detect all unsigned types. Breaking these two into 8 would make it 16 levels of indirection. And then 16 more for detecting all signed types.)

"Do I now have to resort to 8 levels of indirection to detect all 8 types, or is there a better way?" --> Yes, or wait until C allows the same type in a generic.  Sorry.  (You could avoid some  levels with judicious use of UINT_FASTN_MAX, but the worse case is still bad.)

Feels like this was already answered here. Specifically the part pointing out C17 7.20 §4.

@Lundin Okay, do you think this question is valid on its own? If not, I can take it down.

If you do a _Generic on all intn_t from 8 to 64 and their unsigned equivalents, then you have covered all relevant integer types on non-exotic mainstream systems. The only thing that isn't covered is stuff like int and long both being 32 bit types, int32_t is typedef:ed to int but someone passes a long to the macro. The key is to enforce mandatory usage of stdint.h in all contexts, because the default integer types in C are just too broken to be used in portable code.
